# Nodejs websockets client pending promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, promise

Trying to capture all the data from a websocket connection as a nodejs client using a promise. Script is exiting before all the messages are received and console.logging `'Promise { <pending> }'`, I expected it to log 'response #1 | goodbye'.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss:url');

let results = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ws.on('open', function open() {
      ws.send('hello');
    });
    let receivedResults = '';
    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        if (data == 'goodbye') {
            receivedResults += ' | ' + data;
            resolve(result);
        } else {
            receivedResults = data;
        }
    });
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: `try result.then(res => console.log(res))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to log `response #1 | goodbye` you will need to wait for it to resolve.

```
results.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Looks like the promise is still ending early. It was my understanding that a promise wouldn't be done until resolve is called?

It maybe something to do with embedding the resolve in the ws.on('message', function

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are printing `results` it is just a promise object in pending status waiting for resolve, you will not get the result at that moment, it was just recently created. To wait for the resolve you need to execute 'then' method of the promise:

```
results.then(myResponse => {
 console.log(myResponse);
 // do more...
});
```

I recommend this talk to understand the async behavior on node.js
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thanks, i'll review aswell