# Nodejs websocket client, receive multiple messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Building on my problem ([Nodejs websockets client pending promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983890/nodejs-websockets-client-pending-promise)), it appears that promises cannot be used in the conventional way with websockets.

My scenario is:

1. a nodejs client to open a connection to websocket server
2. when a 'hello from server' is received from the server, nodejs client is to respond with a 'hello from client'
3. server will then stream multiple messages to client
4. server will end stream with 'goodbye client'
5. client disconnects

The most promising direction I've found is https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-as-promised however this only handles a finite number of responses using .then. My server will respond with a variable number of responses.

Comment: Promises is not suitable for that kind of behavior, you should use callbacks/handlers.

Comment: My thought is I would use a promise until server sends back 'goodbye client' and then issue disconnect and resolve the promise?